# How to use CDI inside JUnit @BeforeClass

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cdi, junit4, weld-se

I try to use CDI with JUnit. I saw lot of example that implement a custom Runner that uses non-static methods. But i have one more constraint. I use the Cucumber runner on top of JUnit and selenium. So i can't use the BlockJUnit4ClassRunner. I must use the Cucumber Runner.

Any Idea

Comment: what about Mockito.@InjectMocks?

Comment: I don't think. The problem is JUnit that use static Method, Inside this method i can just use static class member. But i can't inject something into static member.

Comment: I daresay you shouldn't rely on `@BeforeClass` for CDI. Instead you should run CDI when you reset your class under test in `@Before`, which is not a static method.

Comment: Yes, but i need to load some data that are common to all test in a suite. So i need to use @BeforeClass